# Getting isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused) error for Kotlin Retrofit post request

Tags: android, rest, kotlin, post, retrofit

I am running a Sample Spring Boot app on my local machine server (localhost) on port 8080. From client app, I was trying to make a post request through Kotlin Retrofit, in my Android Studio **Emulator**,

### Kotlin Code

```
interface RestApi {

    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("users")
    fun addUser(@Body userData: CTUserInfo): Call<ResponseBody>
}


object ServiceBuilder {
    private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()

    fun<T> buildService(service: Class<T>): T{
        return retrofit.create(service)
    }
}

class RestApiService {

    fun addUser(userData: CTUserInfo){

        val retrofit = ServiceBuilder.buildService(RestApi::class.java)

        retrofit.addUser(userData).enqueue(
            object : Callback<ResponseBody> {

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
                    // failure
                    print("Failed") // getting t = below mentioned error
                }

                override fun onResponse( call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {

                    if (response.code() == 201) {
                        // user added
                        print("Success")
                    } else{
                        //user could not be added
                        print("Failed")
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

I am getting below error:

> java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 8080) from /127.0.0.1 (port 57452) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

However, when I am trying to post from Postman it succeeds on `http://localhost:8080/users`.

**How to resolve it?**

#### Update

My Android manifest files looks like,

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application
            android:name=".BaseApplication"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved the issue by adding actual machine `IP` found by running below commands in bash

1. Mac - `ifconfig`
2. Windows - `ipconfig /all`

Example,

```
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://192.168.64.1:8080/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(client)
    .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

have you added permission internet in your manifest? 
and  you have to add    clear teext trafic if you test on a new device whose API is Pie. like this :

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Comment: I updated the post, added my manifest snippet. You see I already have the properties enabled. But no luck.

Comment: can you tell me with technology do you use for Api developement?
because in you adress localhost cannot be reached by android

Comment: in my case to use my api i write my ip adresse not localhost

Comment: I have Spring Boot app running on my localhost. I developed the APIwhich is working fine with Postman

Comment: can you reach the api  with your phone browser?

Comment: I mean you have to  test it 
connect your phone and you pc on the same modem or wifi acess 
test a GET method with your phone by changing localhost with you ip adress

Comment: I am testing in Android Studio simulator which is supposed to connect in localhost on my Mac

Comment: so type 127.0.0.1 not localhost

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding in res/values/xml/network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://localhost:8080/</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and reference this on manifest inside tag application

```
<application
...
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your local backend setup is from Window's subsystem, you have to use the OS' ip instead of `localhost` by using `ifconfig` command from terminal. Use the IP address specified for your development purposes.